# R linear mixed effects- finding individual fixed effects variances (in %)

Tags: r, lme4, variance

(struggling) R user here. I've made some lme4 models, and I am trying to find individual fixed effects variances. I am estimating the variance of the fixed effect components by multiplying the design matrix of the fixed effects with the vector of fixed effect estimates, followed by calculating the variance of these fitted values (As per Nakagawa & Schielzeth, 2013).

I am getting values, however they are sometimes negtive. Is this incorrect?

I also would like to use these values to get the percentage of variance explained, how could this be done? I'm lost when trying to understand all of the maths, and I feel *100 is probably wrong...

Here is an example of my code:

```r
data
     Ho          SP        SL          DP         DL            species
1 0.432 -0.62240975 0.9615917 -0.20535833 -0.8038894 Accipiter gentilis
2 0.355 -0.85728592 1.0821313 -0.07917467 -0.8055025 Accipiter gentilis
3 0.370 -0.91221808 0.7616323 -0.17403906 -0.8041293 Accipiter gentilis
4 0.447 -1.15202246 0.9326085 -0.07640844 -0.8031998 Accipiter gentilis
5 0.452  0.12952583 0.7566257  0.35393076 -0.8058789 Ales Alces
6 0.406 -0.06462976 0.6679433  0.86746704 -0.7952550 Ales Alces
```

```r
lme <- lmer(data$Ho ~ data$SP + data$DP + data$SL + data$DL + (1|data$spp)) 
vector <- fixef(lme)
vector <- vector[-1]
datanew <- data.frame(data$SP, data$DP, data$SL, data$DL)
matrix <- datanew * vector
variance <- data.frame(var(matrix)[1], var(matrix)[2], var(matrix)[3], var(matrix)[4])


 var.matrix..1. var.matrix..2. var.matrix..3. var.matrix..4.
1    0.002225362   1.712515e-05   -0.001885247   -0.001308941
```

Thank you for your time, lmk if you want me to clarify anything.

Comment: Can you give a more complete citation/point to a spot within the paper? Can you also please clarify a little more what you're trying to do? Are you trying to compute effect sizes? https://afex.singmann.science/forums/topic/compute-effect-sizes-for-mixed-objects

Comment: Hi Ben, here is a link to the paper https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x Quote of interest is " Estimating the variance calculated from the fixed effect components of the LMM... can, in principle, be carried out by predicting fitted values based on the fixed effects alone (equivalent to multiplying the design matrix of the fixed effects with the vector of fixed effect estimates) followed by calculating the variance of these fitted values. Yes, overall I want to find how much SP DP SL DL independently affect Ho

Comment: I'll be comparing my results to a similar study that reports the variances in %, however in the method they just cite this paper.

Comment: Is there any more context at all in the "similar study"?  Can you quote the relevant section from that paper? (Can you contact the authors and ask what they did?)

Comment: The similar study states "The variance explained was calculated using the methods
proposed by N & S (2013) as implemented in the MuMIn package, which provides the total variance explained by fixed and random effects and allows the calculation of variance explained by each fixed effect" and in a table description says "Output of linear mixed model analysis: ... percentages of variance explained (variance) ...". In that table there is a total global and a mininmal model var, total parameters var, and var for each parameter SP SL DP DL. 
I'm waiting for a reply from the author, fingers crossed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

It may interest you to check out the `partR2` package, which was developed in part by the same people for getting fixed effect partial R2 values. You can read more about it [from this paper on the package.](https://10.7717/peerj.11414)

Here I give a simple demonstration with the carrots dataset included with `lmerTest`. First you load the requisite libraries: `lmerTest` for the mixed model and `partR2` for the fixed effect R2 values. Then for simplicity's sake I dropped NA values and saved the data, as `partR2` will have issues if you run the data as is since `lmer` will kick out missing values. Normally its wiser to handle missing data in a different way, but I'll skip that for now. Then you fit the model as you normally would. After, save the `partR2` as an object. Here I've used 100 bootstraps but normally its better to use 1000 (its very slow, hence why I use 100 here). Finally I summarize the results at the end:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(lmerTest)
library(partR2)

#### Drop NA Values ####
carrots <- carrots %>% 
  drop_na()

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- lmer(Preference 
            ~ sens2 
            + Homesize 
            + (1| Consumer),
            data=carrots)

#### Extract Part R2 ####
part.fit <- partR2(fit,
       partvars = c("sens2","Homesize"),
       nboot = 100) 

#### Summary ####
summary(part.fit)
```

The summary can be seen here. I recommend reading the paper I cited earlier to know exactly what each portion of the summary means:

```
R2 (marginal) and 95% CI for the full model: 
 R2     CI_lower CI_upper ndf
 0.0643 0.04     0.0897   3  

----------

Part (semi-partial) R2:
 Predictor(s)   R2     CI_lower CI_upper ndf
 Model          0.0643 0.0400   0.0897   3  
 sens2          0.0498 0.0254   0.0754   2  
 Homesize       0.0145 0.0000   0.0425   2  
 sens2+Homesize 0.0643 0.0400   0.0897   1  

----------

Inclusive R2 (SC^2 * R2):
 Predictor IR2    CI_lower CI_upper
 sens2     0.0498 0.0317   0.0721  
 Homesize3 0.0145 0.0018   0.0315  

----------

Structure coefficients r(Yhat,x):
 Predictor SC      CI_lower CI_upper
 sens2      0.8804  0.7369   0.9838 
 Homesize3 -0.4749 -0.6765  -0.1797 

----------

Beta weights (standardised estimates)
 Predictor BW      CI_lower CI_upper
 sens2      0.2235  0.1782   0.2690 
 Homesize3 -0.2800 -0.4284  -0.0976 

----------
```

#### Side Note: Limitations

If you have a fixed effect included as a random slope, I believe `partR2` cannot derive a fixed effect partial effect size. Don't remember why, but something to consider. Another thing to remember is that this package is fairly new (last year in fact), so what can be considered a "weak" or "strong" effect size is yet to be determined. Finally, this package currently only fits gaussian, binomial, and poisson distributions.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, this is really helpful and I will use this package if I don't hear back from the original author!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept either my answer or Bens if you find it was helpful for your question.

Answer (score 2):

I can show you how to do what Nakagawa and Schielzeth describe in their paper, but I'm still not sure how it fits in with what you want to do.

Simulate data and fit example model:

```r
library(lme4)
set.seed(101)
n <- 100
dd <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100), x2 = rnorm(100), x3 = rnorm(100),
                 f = factor(rep(1:10, each = 10)))
dd$y <- simulate(~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|f),
       family = gaussian,
       newdata = dd,
       newparams = list(beta = c(1, 1, 2, 3), theta = 1, sigma = 1))[[1]]
m <- lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|f), data = dd)
```

Here's what they say:

> Estimating sigma^2_f can, in principle, be carried out by predicting fitted values based on the fixed effects alone (equivalent to multiplying the design matrix of the fixed effects with the vector of fixed effect estimates) followed by calculating the variance of these fitted values (Snijders & Bosker 1999).

**However**:

- `sigma^2_f` is a **single** value, not a set of variances corresponding to variances explained by each fixed effect.
- "multiplying" here refers to *matrix* multiplication (technically, matrix-by-vector multiplication)

```r
## multiply fixed-effect model matrix X by FE coefficient vector
pred <- drop(getME(m, "X") %*% fixef(m))
## or equivalently:
pred2 <- predict(m, re.form = NA)
all.equal(pred, pred2) ## TRUE
var(pred)
```

(the last value might need to be multiplied by `(n-1)/n` to conform to S&N's "Note that sigma^2_f should be estimated without degrees-of-freedom correction.")

Note that R^2, variance proportions corresponding to fixed effects, and other related metrics for mixed models are a pretty deep statistical rabbit hole. I have used the [r2glmm package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=r2glmm) to compute partial R^2 values for individual fixed effects within LMMs (not extended to GLMMs).

Comment: I'm actually curious if you have specific papers in mind for this (the fixed effects specifically). I can't imagine I'd understand much of it, but it wouldn't hurt to give them a shot.

Comment: Thank you Ben for your answer, I really appreciate your replies to this question. This helps me understand the maths a little bit more! I can see now that finding sigma^2_f is not meant for the respective fixed effects, and I will go into the rabbit hole a bit further with the partR2 package!